# How to use cutom python library?

Tags: python, swig

I have generated a custom library  for python using Swig and i want to use that library somewhere else (with out the source files) , Should i copy the .so file to that place ? or is there any other way.
Using Swig it has generated one so file(say _example.so) now if i want to use that library in that particular folder i need to do *import example* but if i am trying the same in any other folder it is throwing error saying **'Import Error: no module named example'**.

Comment: `.so` file should be in your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should have generated _example.so and example.py. You need to distribute both. If you are concerned about exposing the sources - do not worry, example.py contains only assets translating python code to calls to the shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before running your command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/directory/with/so/file"
```

Comment: Hi Rodionov,
       i have declared that value also.. anyway i got the issue thank you .... we can need to copy .py file along with .so file both has to exist to work...